# OpenMP for loop does not give correct result

Tags: c, multithreading, gcc, for-loop, openmp

Sorry, I just started learning OpenMP so I am slightly confused. 
I am analyzing my molecular dynamics simulation and in one part of the code I am trying to find the closest distance between water molecules (or ions) and protein. This is very time consuming part because I have around 500000 atoms and around 25000 frames. By single CPU it takes 1 week (for a set of calculations not only the distance).

I changed this part of the code to parallel by OpenMP and it is really fast but with a little bug; 90% of the results (distances) are correct and 10% are wrong, compare to the single CPU code.
This is the part of my code which calculates the closest distance:

```
    ...
    for (i=0; i< number of frames(25000) )
    ...
    // XP,YP,ZP protein coordinates; malloc allocation in the code
    // XI,YI,ZI Sodium molecule coordinates; malloc allocation
    // LX,LY,LZ the dimension of simulation box, malloc allocation
    // dimI defined as a temporary closest distance, filled with very large constant,
    // malloc allocation
    // NSOD number of Sodium molecules
    // rhos keeping the closest distance for each Sodium for each frame.
    …
    ...int l=0,kk=0;
#pragma omp parallel for shared(XI,YI,ZI,XP,YP,ZP,LX,LY,LZ,qq,dimI,distI,rhos,xmin,ymin,zmin,i) private(kk,l)
      for (l=0; l < NSOD; l++){
        // this part relocates every thing inside a box with dimension LX*LY*LZ. xmin, ymin and zmin are the boundaries of the box.
        if (XI[l]!=0.0 || YI[l]!=0.0 || ZI[l]!=0.0){
          if (XI[l] < xmin) XI[l] += ceil((xmin - XI[l])/LX[i-1]) * LX[i-1];
          if (XI[l] > xmax) XI[l] -= ceil((XI[l] - xmax)/LX[i-1]) * LX[i-1];
          if (YI[l] < ymin) YI[l] += ceil((ymin - YI[l])/LY[i-1]) * LY[i-1];
          if (YI[l] > ymax) YI[l] -= ceil((YI[l] - ymax)/LY[i-1]) * LY[i-1];
          if (ZI[l] < zmin) ZI[l] += ceil((zmin - ZI[l])/LZ[i-1]) * LZ[i-1];
          if (ZI[l] > zmax) ZI[l] -= ceil((ZI[l] - zmax)/LZ[i-1]) * LZ[i-1];
        }
        for (kk=0; kk<NP; kk++){

         if ( ( XP[kk]!=0. || YP[kk]!=0. || ZP[kk]!=0. )  ){
           distI[l] = sqrt((XI[l]-XP[kk])*(XI[l]-XP[kk]) + (YI[l]-YP[kk])*(YI[l]-YP[kk]) + (ZI[l]-ZP[kk])*(ZI[l]-ZP[kk]) );
           if (distI[l] < dimI[l] ) {
              dimI[l] = distI[l];
           }
         }
        }
        distI[l] = dimI[l];
        rhos[qq][l] = dimI[l];
```

}
    #pragma omp barrier
        ...

Could you please tell me what is wrong with my code after parallelization? Why only in some cases it gives wrong answer and not all cases? I highly appreciate your comments and recommendation. I am using gcc on linux.
Thank you very much,

Cheers,
Arash

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with floating points it may not be a good idea to have

```
if (XI[l]!=0.0 || YI[l]!=0.0 || ZI[l]!=0.0){
```

instead you should compare with epsilon (being some very small number)

```
if (fabs(XI[l]) > epsilon || ...
```

this could otherwise cause a problem.

Comment: Hi Anders, I will post the result after applying your recommendation, Thanks, Arash

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Anders' answer.

Other than mathematically computing with reals, floating point operations are not associative because of rounding errors. OpenMp changes the order of evaluation of your loop and thus the result will usually be slightly different. You'd have to do a sensitivity analysis to be sure what precision you'd expect of your result and to see if the things that you compute with (or without) OpenMP are within a tolerable range.

Numerics is an art.

Comment: Hi Jens, Thank you for your reply. I changed the if conditions in the way that Anders suggested, but results are the same. About the precision, for example the serial code calculates the distance for the first atom e.g. 2.57 Angstrom (which is absolutely precise), but the parallel code gives 300.12 Angstrom! It shows that the problem of parallel code comes from the inner loop where the closest distance is calculated and specially this line “ `if (distI[l] < dimI[l] ) {dimI[l] = distI[l];}` “ . I will look at the code more carefully and I will post the result. Arash

Comment: This part is in fact bizarre what is it supposed to do? As it is now, it computes the minimum of certain values (those `kk` that fulfill the condition) ? In particular if none of the `kk` fulfills the condition `distI[l]` will not change. My guess that it should be set to `0.0` or `epsilon` in that case.

Comment: Hi Jens, please read my new comment where I cannot find the reason. Arash

Answer (score 0):

My problem has been resolved by chance, although I hate this kind of blind solving problem; therefore I cannot find any explanation for it.
As I mentioned I should find the closest distance between protein-water, protein-Sodium and protein-Chloride. To do this job I need a temporary float variable to compare the new distance with previous one and if it is smaller, then replace the minimum distance. I thought that because I am going to run this on different threads, so it is safer to define a one dimensional float array for this comparison in my code. I defined a 1D float array  `dimI[l]` and I filled it with a very large float number during initialization.

I tried zillion combination of shared and private variables in openmp command in my code and finally I replaced this 1D array with an ordinary float and define it as a private variable; surprisingly it resolved the problem and now it works perfectly.

Why the 1D array does not work as a temporary variable? It seems that it is safer to define a 1D array; regardless of the number of threads, as follows where `kk=0..NSOD` is private and all others are shared variables

```
  Thread 0            T1                  T2                      
  l=0 ..10         l=11..20            l=21..30               
kk1=0..NSOD       kk2=0..NSOD         kk3=0..NSOD  
XI[l],XP[kk1]    XI[l] ,XP[kk2]      XI[l],XP[kk3]
  distI[l]          distI[l]            distI[l]
  dimI[l]           dimI[l]             dimI[l]
```

What is wrong with the above method?

Cheers,
Arash